# Got Error while linking MATLAB with TWS

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, interactive-brokers, tws

I am using MATLAB2017b version & Interactive brokers API version is 9.73 Windows 64bit version. I am unable to register the `Tws.ocx` file & `regsvr32.exe` file through command prompt. If I go to register the file, they show a binary error

[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWi1j.png)

[image]

While executing this command on MATLAB Command window
`ib = ibtws('',7496)`.

They show the error....

> Error using actxserver (line 90)
>   Server creation failed. Invalid ProgID 'TWS.TwsCtrl.1'.
>
> Error in ibtws

Answer (score 0):

As I [explained in detail here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/379473-interactive-brokers-api-connection-error#answer_302305), this is due to an unhandled error in the Trading Toolbox, which relies on the IB ActiveX/COM connector, which changed it ProgID a while ago, thereby causing the toolbox to break.

Consider using the [IB-Matlab](http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/IB-Matlab) connector instead.